# How to make discord bot disconnect from voice channel after playing?

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord, discord.py, python-asyncio

I'm trying to get the discord bot to disconnect from the voice channel after it finishes playing, but I can't use "await" in a lambda expression.

I tried it:

```py
voice_client.play(source=audio_source, after=lambda _: await voice_client.disconnect())
```

But the result is:

```
SyntaxError: 'await' outside async function
```

I tried it:

```py
voice_client.play(source=audio_source, after=lambda _: voice_client.disconnect())
```

But the result is:

```
RuntimeWarning: coroutine 'VoiceClient.disconnect' was never awaited self.after(error)
```

I tried it:

```py
voice_client.play(source=audio_source, after=voice_client.disconnect)
```

But the result is:

```
TypeError: disconnect() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given
```

My solution:

```py
voice_client.play(
    source=audio_source,
    after=lambda _: asyncio.run_coroutine_threadsafe(
        coro=voice_client.disconnect(),
        loop=voice_client.loop
    ).result()
)
```

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: The answer is literally in the FAQ of discord.py... https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/faq.html#how-do-i-pass-a-coroutine-to-the-player-s-after-function

Answer (score 0):

```py
RuntimeWarning: coroutine 'VoiceClient.disconnect' was never awaited self.after(error)
```

`VoiceClient` need to add `await` in front of it. This function is a [coroutine](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-task.html#coroutine).

```py
voice_client.play(source=audio_source, after=lambda _: await voice_client.disconnect())
```

After that you will meet this error

```
SyntaxError: 'await' outside async function
```

You cant use await outside async function

```py
async def func(): #must add async here
    await func2()
```

Try to add `async` at the function of your music command.

```
@bot.commands() #i dont know what type of command you are using, it also can be cogs or slash command
async def yourcommand(args): #add `async` in front `def`
    #your code.....
    voice_client.play(source=audio_source, after=lambda _: await voice_client.disconnect())
```

Comment: I understand, if you see the first example, you will see i tried use await, but await cannot be used on lambda expressions.

Comment: Sorry i didnt see the first example of your code. Please see my edit.

Comment: Thank you for help, your code doesn't work, but i soluciuonteded, see the edit

Comment: I'm glad to hear that. Happy coding :D

Answer (score 0):

[Found this yesterday but commenting for people in the future, this is gone over in the discord.py docs.](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/faq.html#how-do-i-pass-a-coroutine-to-the-player-s-after-function)

To automatically disconnect, put `asyncio.run_coroutine_threadsafe(voice_context.disconnect(), voice_context.loop)` in the lamda expression.

Code example from docs:

```
def my_after(error):
    coro = some_channel.send('Song is done!')
    fut = asyncio.run_coroutine_threadsafe(coro, client.loop)
    try:
        fut.result()
    except:
        # an error happened sending the message
        pass

voice.play(discord.FFmpegPCMAudio(url), after=my_after)
```